# How to find the table name of a column

Tags: mysql

I have a column name and I want to find out which table does this column belongs to? or more like getting the list of tables which has this column in a database in mysql.

Thanks in advance!
Vijay.Sekar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the `information_schema` database:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'your_column_name'
```

Comment: @vijay.sekar Thank him by accepting the answer (click the green check mark to the left of his answer), please.